# Regex - Prevent matching a string with a substring on the same line

Tags: regex

My code (doesn't work)

```
(?!setFeature)[^\n]*"(?:http|ftp):\/\/[\w\d]
```

So, I want to prevent matching of `setFeature("http://xyz")`, but allow matching anything else, for example, `setUrl("http://xyz")`. Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to check if the line doesn't contain `setFeature` without regex?

Comment: Are you trying to do any capturing, or only matching?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck, no, it's a parts of a big system, I would need to change a lot to implement it

Comment: @JordanPilat, capturing. I look for lines which contain http or ftp links and output them with specified 3-lines to the both sides anchor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your [^\n]* is matching "etFeature" since that technically matches your criteria.  You need to add a word boundary to indicate that it must be the start of a word or the beginning of your string, so:

```
\b(?!setFeature)\w+[^\n]*"(?:http|ftp):\/\/[\w\d]
```

You can see [a live test here](https://regex101.com/r/wW1fC3/1).

Comment: But it won't match lines with no words, which contain only links. How to deal with that? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change your look ahead to anchor it to start, and let it match anywhere:

```
^(?!.*setFeature)[^\n]*"(?:http|ftp):\/\/[\w\d]
```